# GlassFish 5, JMS Wrong XAState: 0

Tags: java, transactions, glassfish, jms, xa

I testing my application, reading from queue, but on log catch error:

**DTX5008: Pooling Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wrong XAState: 0**

Singleton
com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration

Consumer
com.example.webhook.outbound.listener.ListenerMessageBean

```
DTX5008 Pooling Exception:  

Cause:  
Exception occurred while closing the connection.  

Solution:  
Check if DB is up and running.
```

ListenerMessageBean not call DB, only send HTTP request over javax.ws.rs.client.Client.

On GlassFish javax.jms.ConnectionFactory enable XATransaction.

domain.xml

```
<connector-connection-pool resource-adapter-name="jmsra" max-pool-size="250" fail-all-connections="true" steady-pool-size="1" name="jms/Example/WebhookOutbound/ConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool" is-connection-validation-required="true" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" transaction-support="XATransaction"></connector-connection-pool>
```

How to fix this error?

Thanx!

GlassFish Server Log

```
[2018-01-25T17:21:52.140+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112140] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.  
sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getTransaction] [[  
  TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=4 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl@596b40ec]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.140+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112140] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.  
sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getTransaction] [[  
  TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=4 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl@596b40ec]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.140+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112140] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.  
sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl] [METHODNAME: registerSynchronization] [[  
  --In JavaEETransactionImpl.registerSynchronization, jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd nonXAResource=null]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.140+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112140] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContain  
er] [METHODNAME: preInvoke] [[  
  Entering BaseContainer::preInvoke : EjbInvocation  componentId=example-webhook-outbound_/example-webhook-outbound,isLocal=true,isRemote=false,isBusinessInterface=true,isWebService=false,isMessageDriven=false,isHome=false,clientInterfac  
e=interface com.example.webhook.outbound.common.__EJB31_Generated__Configuration__Intf__,method=public abstract java.lang.String com.example.webhook.outbound.common.__EJB31_Generated__Configuration__Intf__.getProperty(java.lang.String),ejb  
=null,exception=null,exceptionFromBeanMethod=null,invId=0,wasCancelCalled=false,yetToSubmitStatus=true]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.141+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.org.glassfish.ejb.security.application] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112141] [levelValue: 500]  
[CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager] [METHODNAME: authorize] [[  
  JACC: permission initialized in InvocationInfo: EJBMethodPermission (Name) = Configuration (Action) = getProperty,Local,java.lang.String]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.142+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.org.glassfish.ejb.security.application] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112142] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager] [METHODNAME: authorize] [[  
  JACC: Access Control Decision Result: true EJBMethodPermission (Name) = Configuration (Action) = getProperty,Local,java.lang.String (Caller) = null]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.142+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112142] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getStatus] [[  
  TM: status: Active]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.142+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.org.glassfish.ejb.startup] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112142] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager] [METHODNAME: initializeSingleton] [[  
  SingletonLifeCycleManager: initializingSingleton: example-webhook-outbound#Configuration]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.143+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [org.glassfish.naming] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112143] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory] [METHODNAME: getInitialContext] [[  
  getInitialContext: env={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory}]]  
[2018-01-25T17:21:52.143+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112143] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getTransaction] [[  
  TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=4 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl@596b40ec]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.144+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112144] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: getExistingResourceList] [[  




In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContextImpl ResourceHandler: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContextImpl@1b725273]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.144+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-CDI-00043] [javax.enterprise.resource.weld] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112144] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl] [METHODNAME: getBDAForBeanClass] [[  
  getBDAForBeanClass -- search in example-webhook-outbound for com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.144+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-CDI-00044] [javax.enterprise.resource.weld] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112144] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl] [METHODNAME: getBDAForBeanClass] [[  
  JCDIServiceImpl.getBDAForBeanClass: TopLevelBDA example-webhook-outbound contains beanClassName: com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration.]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.145+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-CDI-00043] [javax.enterprise.resource.weld] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112145] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl] [METHODNAME: getBDAForBeanClass] [[  
  getBDAForBeanClass -- search in example-webhook-outbound for com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.145+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-CDI-00044] [javax.enterprise.resource.weld] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112145] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl] [METHODNAME: getBDAForBeanClass] [[  
  JCDIServiceImpl.getBDAForBeanClass: TopLevelBDA example-webhook-outbound contains beanClassName: com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration.]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.145+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINER] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-28] [timeMillis: 1516890112145] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] [METHODNAME: loadClass] [[  
    Delegating to classloader1 org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.AbstractOSGiModulesRegistryImpl$1@10a13e9]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.146+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-CDI-00043] [javax.enterprise.resource.weld] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112146] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl] [METHODNAME: getBDAForBeanClass] [[  
  getBDAForBeanClass -- search in example-webhook-outbound for com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.146+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-CDI-00044] [javax.enterprise.resource.weld] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112146] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl] [METHODNAME: getBDAForBeanClass] [[  
  JCDIServiceImpl.getBDAForBeanClass: TopLevelBDA example-webhook-outbound contains beanClassName: com.example.webhook.outbound.common.Configuration.]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.147+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112147] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: getExistingResourceList] [[  




In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContextImpl ResourceHandler: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContextImpl@1b725273]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.147+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112147] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: enlistResource] [[  




In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistResource, h=4 h.xares=com.sun.enterprise.resource.XAResourceWrapper@1355d79a tran=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=4 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd localTxStatus=0 syncs=[]]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.148+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112148] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: enlistXAResource] [[  




In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistXAResource, h=4 h.xares=com.sun.enterprise.resource.XAResourceWrapper@1355d79a tran=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=4 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd localTxStatus=0 syncs=[]]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.148+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112148] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: enlistXAResource] [[  
In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistXAResource - enlistable]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.148+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112148] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl] [METHODNAME: enlistResource] [[  
  --In JavaEETransactionImpl.enlistResource, jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd nonXAResource=null]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.148+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jta] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112148] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionState] [METHODNAME: startAssociation] [[  
  startAssociation for com.sun.enterprise.resource.XAResourceWrapper@1355d79a]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.148+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jta] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112148] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionState] [METHODNAME: startAssociation] [[  
  startAssociation for known resource]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.148+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.jta] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112148] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionState] [METHODNAME: startAssociation] [[  
  startAssociation in state: 0]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.150+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINER] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-28] [timeMillis: 1516890112150] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] [METHODNAME: loadClass] [[  
    Searching local repositories]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.150+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINER] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-28] [timeMillis: 1516890112150] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] [METHODNAME: findClass] [[  
      findClass(com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Legend)]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.150+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [enterprise_distributedtx.pooling_excep] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112150] [levelValue: 900] [[  
  DTX5008: Pooling Exception:  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wrong XAState: 0  
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionState.startAssociation(TransactionState.java:375)  
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:212)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:660)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistXAResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:1313)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistResource(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:371)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.enlistComponentResources(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:1339)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.postInvoke(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:640)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionInvocationHandler.beforePostInvoke(TransactionInvocationHandler.java:95)  
        at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.postInvoke(InvocationManagerImpl.java:225)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1740)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:424)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:74)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:647)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:389)  
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)  
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.checkInit(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:361)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.CMCSingletonContainer._getContext(CMCSingletonContainer.java:116)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2613)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2005)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)  
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy318.getProperty(Unknown Source)  
        at com.example.webhook.outbound.common.__EJB31_Generated__Configuration__Intf____Bean__.getProperty(Unknown Source)  
        at com.example.webhook.outbound.listener.ListenerMessageBean.onMessage(ListenerMessageBean.java:38)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)  
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4820)  
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:824)  
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)  
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)  
        at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4792)  
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4780)  
        at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1222)  
        at org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)  
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy335.onMessage(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:283)  
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:107)  
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)  
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)  
]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.151+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112151] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: handleResourceError] [[  
  TM: HandleResourceError com.sun.enterprise.resource.XAResourceWrapper@1355d79a, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wrong XAState: 0]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.151+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112151] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getTransaction] [[  
  TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=4 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl@5b527acd localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl@596b40ec]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.151+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112151] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: getExistingResourceList] [[  




In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContextImpl ResourceHandler: org.glassfish.ejb.mdb.MessageBeanContextImpl@1b725273]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.150+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINER] [] [javax.enterprise.web.util] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-28] [timeMillis: 1516890112150] [levelValue: 400] [CLASSNAME: org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader] [METHODNAME: findClass] [[  
        findClassInternal(com.sun.webui.jsf.component.Legend)]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.152+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112152] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getStatus] [[  
  TM: status: Active]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.152+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112152] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: suspendXA] [[  
  TM: suspend]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.153+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINEST] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112153] [levelValue: 300] [CLASSNAME: CurrentImpl] [METHODNAME: suspend()] [[  
  Current thread has been disassociated from control :com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.ControlImpl@463216ff]]  
[2018-01-25T17:21:52.152+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [AS-WEB-NAMING-00005] [javax.enterprise.web.naming] [tid: _ThreadID=98 _ThreadName=Thread-28] [timeMillis: 1516890112152] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext] [METHODNAME: file] [[  
  File cannot be read /home/glassfish/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__admingui/WEB-INF/classes/com/sun/webui/jsf/component/Legend.class]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.153+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112153] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getStatus] [[  
  TM: status: NoTransaction]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.153+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112153] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl] [METHODNAME: <init>] [[  
  --Created new JavaEETransactionImpl, txId = 5]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.154+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112154] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getTransaction] [[  
  TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=5 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl@596b40ec]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.154+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112154] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: enlistComponentResources] [[  
  TM: enlistComponentResources]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.154+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112154] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate] [METHODNAME: getTransaction] [[  
  TM: getTransaction: tx=JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=5 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=0 syncs=[], tm=com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl@596b40ec]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.154+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112154] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified] [METHODNAME: getExistingResourceList] [[  




In JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.getExistingResourceList,  ResourceHandler type: com.sun.ejb.containers.SimpleEjbResourceHandlerImpl ResourceHandler: com.sun.ejb.containers.SimpleEjbResourceHandlerImpl@6ebbf985]]  


[2018-01-25T17:21:52.154+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [FINE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 5] [timeMillis: 1516890112154] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl] [METHODNAME: registerSynchronization] [[  
  --In JavaEETransactionImpl.registerSynchronization, jtsTx=null nonXAResource=null]]
```